# Is it possible to internationalise a setup project in Visual Studio 2003 (.net 1.1)?

Tags: internationalization, installation, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I'm developing an app in .net 1.1 with VS 2003. Is it possible to internationalise its setup project so it could show up in different languages? Custom dialogues included, of course :D.

If it is possible... can you link to some kind of tutorial?

I've found this forum thread on [How to I18N a Setup project](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-internationalization/589/How-to-I18N-a-Setup-project) but the proposed solution looks quite complex, I wonder if there could be an easier path.

Thx for your time!